Configure in memory collection in WebApplicationFactory for .net 8.0
My application was in .NET CORE 3.0 and i am upgrading it with .NET 8.0.
My integration test project use some of the config value MemoryCollection instead of AppSettings. same value i want to use in .NET 8.0 integration test project. but it always take value from appsettings.
I have configured in memory value from WebApplicationFactory class.
Below is my code.
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);

    builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
    {
        config.AddInMemoryCollection(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DataProtect:File", "Data/protect.pfx")
        });
    });

    builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        
    });

    builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
    {
        
        // Mock external dependency
        services.SwapService(Substitute.For<ITestService>());
    });
}

In AppSettings.Development.Json
 "DataProtect": {
   "File": "./bin/Debug/net8/Data/protect.pfx",
   "CertificatePassword": "******"
 }

I want File : 'Data/protect.pfx' value in integration test project.

Was not able to reproduce. Can you please add a full [mre]?
